# How to increase page performance in Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I want to keep a track which pages are mostly accessed and heavy traffic.
And page can be accessible to more user at any instant of time. 
As number of users increased then login page is not loading and site goes very slow..

I want to know or save page **loading time/Network Bandwidth**. How it will possible?

Solutions and tricks tips are welcome.

Comment: It's difficult to effectively answer this without knowing what your bottleneck is.

Comment: For exaample of login page. After login of 40 users . its not possible to log in. Performance is hampered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer the below MSDN link

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647813.aspx)

Also the below link

[Performance tuning](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article45.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Performance is a very major factor for any application and for achieving this you have to go through on various parts of the web programming like: 
well designed data architecture,
using Cache,
Background Processing, using stored procedure and many more.

Please visit this link which help you to do the same:
[10 Tips for Writing High-Performance Web Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163854.aspx)
[Improving ASP.NET Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647787.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find bottlenecks on the page and see what is taking the longest. You can use [Dottrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) that is a nice add-on for visual studio. You can profile different stages on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Performance tuning includes lot and more. Please refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163854.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could use web method in the .cs file of your page and call this method via ajax. By doing that, your page will not post back, thus enhance performance. See [more information here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/334158/Call-Webservice-using-javascript).